# Not able to get downloadUri after upload video to storage firebase

Tags: android

after uploading the video to storage firebase I can't get download URI and this is the error

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
```

I want to fix this error to upload this URI in database

### my code:

java

```
    package com.example.rami_.esmatsongs;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.SetOptions;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

public class AddPost extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText titleEdt;
    private EditText descriptionEdt;
    private VideoView videoView;
    private ImageView addVideo;
    private Button share;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private FirebaseStorage storage;
    private StorageReference storageRef;
    private Uri  videoUri = null;
    private String title;
    private TextView test;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_post);
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        storage =FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        //storageRef = storage.getReference();
        storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        titleEdt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addTitle);
        descriptionEdt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addDescription);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.addVideo);
        addVideo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addnewVideo);
        share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addPostBtn);
        test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        // add video from gallery
        addVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            }
        });

        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                title = titleEdt.getText().toString().trim();
                // check title
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(title))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(AddPost.this,"Please Enter title",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                // check  if user add video or not
                else if(videoUri == null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(AddPost.this,"Please Add Video",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    // get id
                    String id= UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                    Map<String , Object> postMap = new HashMap<>();
                    postMap.put("Description" , descriptionEdt.getText().toString().trim());
                    postMap.put( "id", id);
                    postMap.put("likes", 0);
                    postMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
                    postMap.put("title", titleEdt.getText().toString().trim());
                    postMap.put("uri", videoUri+"");

                    // add post to firebase and go to main
                    firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").document(id).set(postMap, SetOptions.merge()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Intent  intent = new Intent(AddPost.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(AddPost.this, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    });
                    }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // get video uri and set in videoView
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            videoUri = data.getData();
            try{
                videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
                MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(AddPost.this);
                mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoView);
                videoView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);

                // add video to firebase storage
                String randomName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                StorageReference filePath = storageRef.child("videos").child(randomName+".mp4");
                UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putFile(Uri.parse(videoUri+""));
                Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            throw task.getException();
                        }
                        test.setText(storageRef.getDownloadUrl()+"");
                        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                        return storageRef.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        videoUri = downloadUri;
                    }
                });
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This must return download URI.

Answer (score 0):

i have done my task this way:-

```
File file =new File(mediaPath);
        if(file.exists()) {
            UploadTask uploadTask = mReference.putFile(Uri.fromFile(file),metadata);
            Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }

                    // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                    return mReference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    getUploadedMediaPath.getUploadedFileUrl(downloadUri.toString());
                }
            });
        }
```